# how to divide all the values of columns with respect of a row?

Tags: pyspark

How I can divide all rows with the values of the last row:

```
col col col3
'A'  2    3
'B'  8    9
'C'  7    5
'fre' 12  13
```

I wana divide the value of the whole col2 by 12 and col3 by 13:

```
col col col3
'A'  2/12    3/13
'B'  8/12    9/13
'C'  7/12    5/13
'fre' 12/12  13/13
```

Please give a way whose work for a large number of columns. I wanna do that for all columns except the first column. (as above example)

Comment: How do you define what the last row is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating under the assumption that the id of the last col is unique:

If you need to iterate over large numbers of columns

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('A',2,3), 
        ('B',8,9),
        ('C',7,5),
        ('fre',12,13)
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

# Get last row
lr = df.tail(1)[0]
# Get last row col1 for otherwise
l_col1 = lr[0]


for c, v in zip(df.columns[1:], lr[1:]):
  df = df.withColumn(c, when(col('col1')!=l_col1, col(c)/v).otherwise(v))
```

If you want to divide the last column as well

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('A',2,3), 
        ('B',8,9),
        ('C',7,5),
        ('fre',12,13)
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

# Get last row
lr = df.tail(1)[0]
# Get last row col1 for 
l_col1 = lr[0]


for c, v in zip(df.columns[1:], lr[1:]):
  df = df.withColumn(c, col(c)/v)
```

Comment: I have many columns, can't do it manually like this

Comment: its ok to do division in the last row if its easier

Comment: Updated to handle any number of columns

Comment: also I tried for 1 column but why I get `cold calling`

Comment: please see edit

Comment: fixed one last time